# Why is this a generalized pivotal quantity?

Tags: confidence-interval, pivot

I am reading ["Generalized Confidence Intervals" by Weerahandi](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/01621459.1993.10476355), and I'm trying to get my head around the definition of a *generalized pivotal quantity.* I understand what a (regular) pivotal quantity is.

This is definition 2.1 in the paper:

---

Let $ = r(\mathbf{X}; \mathbf{x}, \nu)$ be a function of $\mathbf{X}, \mathbf{x}, \nu$ (but not necessarily a function of all), where $\nu = (\theta, \delta)$. If $R$ has the following two properties, then it is said to be a *generalized pivotal quantity:*

1. $R$ has a probability distribution free of unknown parameters.
2. The observed pivotal, defined as $r_{\text{obs}} = r(\mathbf{x}; \mathbf{x}, \nu)$, does not depend on the nuisance parameter $\delta$.

---

I don't really have an intuition for the purpose of two independent copies of the data, yet. So, I started looking at examples, hoping that would help me. They give the following example of a pivotal quantity for the Behrens-Fisher problem:

$$
R = (\bar{X} - \bar{Y} - \theta)\left(\frac{\sigma_x^2 s^2_x / (mS_X^2) + \sigma^2_ys_y^2/(nS_Y^2)}{\sigma^2_x/m + \sigma^2_Y/n}  \right)^{1/2}.
$$

**Why is this a generalized pivotal quantity?** When you set $\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{X}$ and $\mathbf{y} = \mathbf{Y}$, then you get $(\bar{x} - \bar{y} - \theta)$, and that has a distribution that is dependent on the unknown nuisance variance parameters. Is it because the observed values are nonrandom now?

Comment: $(\bar{x} - \bar{y} - \theta)$ is a constant and not a random variable; ($\bar{X} - \bar{Y} - \theta)$ is the random variable. Therefore, $(\bar{x} - \bar{y} - \theta)$ does not depend on the variance parameters in the sense that it is not a function of the variance parameters. Could that be the meaning?

Comment: @Cat yep that’s it. Distribution is not the representation. I was about to delete the question, but I don’t want to rob you of the points if you wanted to type that up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(\bar{x} - \bar{y} - \theta)$ is a constant and not a random variable. $(\bar{X} - \bar{Y} - \theta)$ is the random variable. Therefore, $r_\text{obs}$ in this case does not "depend on" the variance parameters in the sense that it is not a function of the variance parameters. Hence, condition 2 --- despite being poorly worded --- is satisfied.

Comment: One thing: randomness doesn’t matter here. When you write down the letters for the random variable there’s no non-theta parameter that shows up. That’s true whether or not you think of it as random. “Depends on” and “function are ambiguous here, yes. It’s not the density or cdf function, it’s the “what you write down” function.